# Fix "should not use basic type string as key in context.WithValue" golint

Tags: go, golint

I am passing an uuid in using the `Context` and `WithValue` to subsequent functions that handle this `*http.request`. This uuid is was passed in the authorization header to a REST call to identify a person. The authorization token is verified and needs to accessible to check if the call is itself is authorized.

I used:

```
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), string("principal_id"), *id)
```

But golint complains:

```
should not use basic type string as key in context.WithValue
```

What is the best option that could be used to retrieve this key that is not a basic type like a simple string?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Just use a key type:

```golang
type key int

const (
    keyPrincipalID key = iota
    // ...
)
```

Since you've defined a separate type, it will never collide. Even if you have two packages, `pkg1.key(0) != pkg2.key(0)`.

See also: [Go Blog about key collisions in context](https://blog.golang.org/context#TOC_3.2.).

Comment: What if I'm passing the context to a different module (where the unexported `key` is not available)?

Comment: @endorama You must provide exported getters and maybe setters. `PrincipalIDFromCtx(context.Context) (int64)` and `CtxWithPrincipalID(context.Context, int64) (context.Context)`.

Comment: Should these methods go in pkg1, pkg2 or both? I see possible cycle dependencies if only in pkg1 or pkg2. 
Having such method in both makes sense, but that produces duplicated code.

Answer (score 23):

Use type `struct{}` much better.

```golang
type ctxKey struct{} // or exported to use outside the package

ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, ctxKey{}, 123)
fmt.Println(ctx.Value(ctxKey{}).(int) == 123) // true
```

Reference: https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue

> The provided key must be comparable and should not be of type string or any other built-in type to avoid collisions between packages using context. Users of WithValue should define their own types for keys. To avoid allocating when assigning to an interface{}, context keys often have concrete type struct{}. Alternatively, exported context key variables' static type should be a pointer or interface.

Answer (score 7):

I achieve the above by doing the following and feel it's pretty clean

```
package util

import "context"

type contextKey string

func (c contextKey) String() string {
    return string(c)
}

var (
    // ContextKeyDeleteCaller var
    ContextKeyDeleteCaller = contextKey("deleteCaller")
    // ContextKeyJobID var
    ContextKeyJobID contextKey
)

// GetCallerFromContext gets the caller value from the context.
func GetCallerFromContext(ctx context.Context) (string, bool) {
    caller, ok := ctx.Value(ContextKeyDeleteCaller).(string)
    return caller, ok
}

// GetJobIDFromContext gets the jobID value from the context.
func GetJobIDFromContext(ctx context.Context) (string, bool) {
    jobID, ok := ctx.Value(ContextKeyJobID).(string)
    return jobID, ok
}
```

..and then set on context by,

```
ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), util.ContextKeyDeleteCaller, "Kafka Listener")
```

..get value from context by,

```
caller, ok := util.GetCallerFromContext(ctx)
if !ok {
    dc.log.Warn("could not get caller from context")
}
fmt.Println("value is:", caller) // will be 'Kafka Listener'
```

and can print out value of key by doing,

```
fmt.Println("Key is:", ContextKeyDeleteCaller.String())
```

Answer (score -11):

Sharing a brief answer for the above question.
[GitHub Link](https://github.com/mgechev/revive/blob/master/fixtures/golint/context-keys-type.go)
In short, `context.WithValue()` needs `interface{}` type as **keys** and **values**.

I hope this helps.
Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure I get the comment - string should work as a parameter to function that takes input as interface{}

Comment: @SaurabhNayar That is no Golang idiomatic way. You would get GoLinter warnings.

Comment: this doesn't seem actually related to the question. The question is about a linter warning when using plain `string` types as context keys.